# Sign-up Policy issuing two tokens

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a signup policy setup to redirect to my web app, and my web app reads the claims to collect information about a user. Two users in my application were having sign-up difficulty. When there's a signup error my application writes all the claims to a log. The claims of these two users did not match the Output claims of my sign-up policy, they were missing a lot of claims. After some investigating in Azure I noticed in the Audit Logs of those two users there was:

1. Add User
2. Issue token(sign-up policy)
3. Issue token(sign-up policy again)

For both users this second token issue happened 30-45 seconds after the initial issue. Every other account I check only has the first two(Add and issue once). It's not possible for the user to sign-up twice, so why would it issue a second token? When I look at the error log the claim "iat" is from the second token. What would trigger a second issuance? Or what might stop the first token from reaching my application?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even if it triggered the same policy twice, the claim set should be exactly the same; its not really relevant that it launched twice, nor is it a clue as to what the issue is in my experience. In the case that these claims are read from the directory, did you confirm that the accounts have this data written to the user account?

Comment: Thanks Jas. Where would I find all the persisted data? When I look at accounts under Users it only has their username, first name and last name. However this is a sign-up policy so I'm not sure if they are read from the directory or from the actual sign-up form.

Comment: Try using Microsoft Graph API Explorer

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jas. I was unable to get the Graph API Explorer working. I couldn't even get a list of users. I will look in to altering the way my sign-up flow works instead. Thanks